# How to use Python placeholders in a web browser string

Tags: python, browser

I need to format a string and send it to a web browser with the splinter module.
I usually use placeholder, but this time it doesn't work.
This is the string I want to pass to the browser:

```
http://NAMESERVER:8082/ViewObjectRes//TransactionLogManagerPostErrorHandling\%28Instance+0\%29\%3Ainstance\%3DInstance+0
```

where NAMESERVER is the fqdn of the server which I want to connect to.
I tried use the placeholder as usual but I get an error:

```
print ("http://%s:8082/ViewObjectRes//TransactionLogManagerPostErrorHandling\\%28Instance+0\\%29\\%3Ainstance\\%3DInstance+0" % "TEST")

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I guess should escape all the other percentage sign, but I tried without success.

Comment: Your guess is correct. Can you show us your try?

Comment: After your confirmation, I was able to search better and find the solution. I used double percentage sign %%. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly easier, with a url that might contain `%`, to use format?

```
print "http://{}:8082/ViewObjectRes//TransactionLogManagerPostErrorHandling\\%28Instance+0\\%29\\%3Ainstance\\%3DInstance+0".format("TEST")
```

Comment: I had complitely neglected to study the format function... it looks more elegant than placeholder for my purpose. Thank you.